# WebSphere MQ .NET - Difference between IBM.XMS.dll and amqmdnet.dll

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I've used .NET quite extensively but I'm pretty new to WebSphere MQ. I need to create a .NET application that reads messages off the MQ. I keep seeing articles referencing either the IBM.XMS or amqmdnet libraries.

I **think** I'm supposed to be using the IBM.XMS library but what exactly is the difference between these two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IBM.XMS is the IBM's implementation of JMS specification in C#. You need to use IBM.XMS if you need JMS style of messaging in C# or any other language of .NET framework. On the other hand amqmdnet is the MQ's native API implementation, something similar to C MQI but it's in C# and is Object oriented. Use amqmdnet if you want MQ native style of messaging.

HTH.

Comment: Also I believe amqmdnet.dll is useful for polling type of implementations with MQ while IBM.XMS is good for publish/subscribe implementations.

Comment: Not really. Both implementations are suited for Point-to-Point and Publish/Subscribe messaging patterns. XMS supports (1) OnMessage listener, (2) Message properties which are not there in Base .NET (amqmdnet) implementation.